# Saving ModelForm error(User_Message could not be created because the data didn't validate)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I came across a thread that seemed like it might be related at djangocode but it didn't really help. I'm trying to save a modelform and it's throwing an exception.  I think that it might be related to referring to the same foreign key twice in my model.  It might also have to do with the definition of unique=True in one of the foreign key fields.  I don't know

```
class User_Message(models.Model):
   recipient=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name="recipients")
   subject=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   sender=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="senders")
   message=models.TextField(max_length=500)
sent=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.subject



if request.method=="POST" and request.POST['id_message']:
    messageform=User_MessageForm(request.POST)
    recipient=[]   #receiver of mail must be a list
    recipient.append(post.user)
    if messageform.is_valid:
        message=messageform.save(commit=False)
        message.sender=user
        message.recipient=post.user
        return HttpResponse('%s %s' %(user,post.user))
        message.save()

        #send the email
        subject=messageform.cleaned_data['id_subject']
        body=messageform.cleaned_data['id_message']

        try:
            send_mail(subject, body, sender, recipient)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
```

It's failing at the line, `messageform.save(commit=False)`.  Man I thought that statement was fail proof.

The POST data that is received by the modelform contains the subject and message fields. This data is successfully validated by my modelform.

Is it the related names, the `unique=True`... what gives?

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if messageform.is_valid:
```

That line needs to be

```
if messageform.is_valid():
```

Basically, the error comes from calling `save()` on an invalid form.

Comment: I'm actually sorry on this one. I should have caught that. I'm tired and trying to do way too much.  You have helped me tremendously today, Yuji

Comment: No prob man! I wouldn't have caught that if I didn't read into the error message and go check out what the code was flipping out about -- turns out it was just `forms.errors`, which should never happen at save(), and then I noticed the ().

Comment: Oh, Hallelujah! I fell in the same pitfall.